# Mysql Column constraint as "not empty" / "required"

Tags: mysql

Can we specify a column in mysql as "not empty" / "required". The requirement is to ensure that the field never remains blank on any record insertion.

Comment: please use `NOT NULL` and refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-defaults.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you don't want blank (empty string, as opposed to `NULL`) values to be allowed in the table either.

Normally, that's what a `CHECK` constraint for. You do something like

```
CREATE TABLE
        mytable
        (
        myfield NOT NULL VARCHAR(200),
        CHECK(myfield > '')
        )
```

However, `MySQL` parses the constraint but does not enforce it. You are still allowed to insert empty values.

To work around that, create a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger and raise a signal on an attempt to insert a blank value:

```
CREATE TRIGGER
        tr_mytable_bi
BEFORE INSERT
ON      mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        IF NEW.myfield = '' THEN
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Blank value on mytable.myfield';
        END IF;
END;
```

Do the same on `BEFORE UPDATE` if you want to forbid updates to a blank value as well.

Answer (score 6):

MySQL8 now has value constraints, which allows you to implement value restrictions without using triggers

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    myfield VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT myfield_not_empty CHECK(
            LENGTH(myfield) > 0 
        )
);
```

Will ensure the values in `myfield` will never be empty

Answer (score 2):

Use `NOT NULL`.

It causes input to be *required*.
But a field to be not empty you need validation script explicitly.

Example:

```
create table example(
  login_name varchar(16) not null
  pass_word varchar(32) not null
);
```

**Refer to**: [Wiki on Null (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29)

Comment: I have used "NOT NULL" but still the insert command runs fine and a row is inserted in the table(using sqlyog). But doing same through the command line terminal throws an error(as desired). I am not sure if this is due to the mode difference between the twos.

Answer (score -1):

You can define the column as NOT NULL as answered by @Ravinder

In addition to it you can set a default value to a column. If we take the example of previous answer, we can do it as below:

`create table example(
  login_name varchar(16) = null
  pass_word varchar(32) = null
);`

Here if no value is received for these columns then NULL will be inserted by default.

Comment: That is an invalid `create table` statement. What is `= NULL` supposed to do?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, mybad. I declared here the syntax of a stored procedure where we want to set a default value for a column of a table.