# How do I require a mysql field?

Tags: mysql, field

I just discovered NOT NULL does not make a field required.

When creating a mysql table, how do I create a field that cannot contain null or blank (must have something in it)?

Comment: `NOT NULL` *does* make a field "required" in the sense that it needs to have a value stored.  `NULL` means "no value".  According to MySQL, a blank string is still a "value".  I'd suggest having your client check if it's blank before inserting the data.

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24424363

Comment: you can add a `CHECK` constraint to disallow inserts or updates to "" or whatever other "semantic" null value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql Column constraint as "not empty" / "required"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424363/mysql-column-constraint-as-not-empty-required)

Comment: @MikeD: Problem is, in MySQL it doesn't actually *enforce* those.  It'll parse it and add it, but it won't check it before an insert.  Not quite sure why.

Comment: Or see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514178/im-looking-for-a-constraint-to-prevent-the-insert-of-an-empty-string-in-mysql

Comment: @RocketHazmat true ... just seen when following the links ... so use PRE-INSERT & PRE-UPDATE triggers ... one doesn't have to like those though

Comment: NOT NULL won't work .. the reason I found out it doesn't work is I did an insert and did not provide anything for the field and it accepted emptiness.  If MySQL would allow me to do this "NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL" then it would work because if I didn't provide a value for the field and it attempted to default it to NULL then it would error out.  This to me is a MySQL oversight because the database designer should be able to say a field must contain a value forcing all future programmers to comply.  Of course I know that I can force a value on the interface side or provide a default value.

Comment: @XiVix: Remember, a blank string is considered a "value" by MySQL.

Comment: I think you should do two things: Set the column to `NOT NULL` *and* create a trigger to check if the column is properly filled. See my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, MySQL accepts invalid values.  You can set MySQL to strict mode to force valid values.  This will reject a query that does not provide a value for a NOT NULL column as well as enforce integrity on all types of columns.

---

**Update:** MySQL 5.7 and above now have strict mode on by default.  So it would not accept invalid values by default like previous versions.

---

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-important

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables

Edit:
@Barranka and @RocketHazmat made good points in the comments.  `''` is not the same as null, so MySQL will allow that in a NOT NULL column.  In that instance, you would have to resort to your code or a trigger.

In the code (PHP for example), this could be easy enough, running something like:

```
if (!strlen($value)) { 
    // Exclude value or use NULL in query
}
```

Comment: can I do this just for a specific table or query or is it global?

Comment: I'm not sure about per table.  I know you can set it in the config file and you can set it in each session `SET sql_mode = ...;`

Comment: I like to keep strict mode on in all of my databases, then program with that in mind.  This makes sure that your program isn't inserting any invalid values as well.  You set the parameters for the columns when creating the table, why not abide by them?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do two things:

1. Set the column to `NOT NULL` to force the input of a value
2. Use a trigger to validate the values.

   Within the trigger you can cancel the operation if the desired column does not fulfill a required condition (for example, having zero-length).

[This question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538786/how-to-abort-insert-operation-in-mysql-trigger) address this second thing, and here is an example:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `cancel_insert_if_empty`
BEFORE INSERT ON `your_table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    declare msg varchar(255);
    if NEW.your_column is null or length(NEW.your_column) = 0 then
        set msg = "You're doing something wrong! Now suffer the consequences";
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
    end if;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

In this example, if you try to insert a `null` value or a zero-length string in `your_column` an error will rise and the insert will be canceled. Quoting from [the reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/trigger-syntax.html):

> MySQL handles errors during trigger execution as follows:
>
> - If a `BEFORE` trigger fails, the operation on the corresponding row is not performed.
> - A `BEFORE` trigger is activated by the attempt to insert or modify the row, regardless of whether the attempt subsequently succeeds.
> - An error during either a `BEFORE` or `AFTER` trigger results in failure of the entire statement that caused trigger invocation.

Of course, you can write a trigger to check the updates too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a bunch but I was trying to avoid using a trigger so I went with Devon and the strict approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value for that field:    City varchar(40) DEFAULT 'Sandnes'

Comment: This won't work if the user specifically inserts a zero-length string. Example: `insert into a_table(a_column) values('');`

Comment: @Barranka, true.  But technically that isn't null.  So MySQL won't know the difference and then yes, you would need something like your answer.